# Add taxonomy in CPT automatically

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to add a new category in a CPTA every time I add a category in CPTB (automatically).

I found this code to add a new category every time I add a new page. The category has the same name as title post.

My goal. I should have the same categories in CPT-A and CPT-B, every time I add a new category in CPTA duplicate in CPTB. I know I can assign 1 taxonomy to both CPT, but then if I check the category 'cars' I will have results from CPTA and CPTB. That's the main reason to make 2 different taxonomies.

```
function update_custom_terms($post_id) {

    // only update terms if it's a post-type-B post
    if ( 'page' != get_post_type($post_id)) {
        return;
    }

    // don't create or update terms for system generated posts
    if (get_post_status($post_id) == 'auto-draft') {
        return;
    }

    /*
    * Grab the post title and slug to use as the new 
    * or updated term name and slug
    */
    $term_title = get_the_title($post_id);
    $term_slug = get_post( $post_id )->post_name;

    /*
    * Check if a corresponding term already exists by comparing 
    * the post ID to all existing term descriptions. 
    */
    $existing_terms = get_terms('category', array(
        'hide_empty' => false
        )
    );

    foreach($existing_terms as $term) {
        if ($term->description == $post_id) {
            //term already exists, so update it and we're done
            wp_update_term($term->term_id, 'category', array(
                'name' => $term_title,
                'slug' => $term_slug
                )
            );
            return;
        }
    }

    /* 
    * If we didn't find a match above, this is a new post, 
    * so create a new term.
    */
    wp_insert_term($term_title, 'category', array(
        'slug' => $term_slug,
        'description' => $post_id
        )
    );
}

//run the update function whenever a post is created or edited
add_action('save_post', 'update_custom_terms');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wordpress plugin **Custom Post Type UI** to create both custom post type and taxonomy.

Comment: Its not about use plugins, its about (automatically). The first line 'I am trying to add a new category in a CPTA every time I add a category in CPTB (automatically).'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *create_term* hook read more at 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/create_term/